# If$ f(0) = 1$ and $f(n) = 4f(n-1) +n$, then $f(n) = O(4^n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Everyone. I've been trying induction proofs of this for hours now. I know that $n + 1$ is less than $f(n)$ for large n. I haven't been able to use that. I've tried breaking one of the $4^n$ terms. I've been using $\alpha$ as the constant. I can see that f(n) lives between $4^n$ and $2\cdot 4^n$, but I can't bring that upper bound down for a strong induction proof. I feel like I'm missing something here. Any hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $f(n)=0(4^n)$ ????? What do you mean?

Comment: That's big-O notation.

Comment: Thanks for making it look better. I want to learn that stuff. It's just hard to do so and keep up on difficult homework at the same time...

Comment: Or even easier: divide recurrence by $4^n$ and get recurrence for $g(n)=f(n)/4^n$. Show that $g(n)=O(1)$.

Comment: Nice approaches. I'll give those a try and gratefully check the question answered as soon I as feel I can bring one of those approaches home. Thanks!

Comment: @A.S.  I think f(n) = 4^n +2n(n-1) + n < 2*4^n for large n. I used the formula for the sum of the first n numbers, found the pattern, etc. Does that look like what you had in mind?

Comment: The spirit is correct, but what you should be summing are not the first n numbers, but first n numbers multiplied by decreasing powers of 4 - you seem to have lost them. Recheck your derivation.

Comment: @A.S. Ah, I'll go back and try again. I'm probably getting tired. Still, I have a new approach that I think will work, and I thank you for that. Perhaps you could let me know what the answer is. I still have to prove it. But I'll be more confident that I'm right when I manage the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way of doing it is to find an explicit formula for $f(n)$. (There may be an easier way, but finding an explicit form for $f(n)$ turns out to be manageable)

We will first ignore the requirement that $f(0)=1$ and try to find a linear solution $h(n)$ for the recurrence of the form
$$ h(n) = an + b $$

Substituting this into the recurrence relation gives us that
$$ an + b = h(n) = 4h(n-1) + n = 4a(n-1) + 4b + n = (4a+1)n + 4b - 4a$$

We thus require that
$$ a = 4a+1 \quad \text{ and } \quad b = 4b - 4a$$

The first equation gives us that
$$ a = -\frac{1}{3}$$
and substituting this into the second equation gives us that
$$ b = -\frac{4}{9} $$

Thus one possible solution to the recurrence is

$$ h(n) = -\frac{n}{3} - \frac{4}{9} $$

We now try to find the general solution to the recurrence. (i.e. All possible solutions. Showing that some particular solution is $O(4^n)$ doesn't show that all of them are. Also, the solution we have found doesn't satisfy $f(0)=1$, so we need to rectify that.)

To this end, let 
$$ f(n) = g(n) - \frac{n}{3} - \frac{4}{9} = g(n) + h(n) $$
where $h(n)$ is the particular solution we found above.

Then the recurrence becomes
$$ g(n) + h(n) = 4g(n-1) + 4h(n-1) + n $$

But
$$ h(n) = 4h(n-1)+n $$
so we are left with
$$ g(n) = 4g(n-1) $$
which is easy to solve. We get that $g(n) = A \cdot 4^n $ for some constant $A$.

Thus all possible solutions to the recurrence are given by
$$ f(n) = A \cdot 4^n - \frac{n}{3} - \frac{4}{9} $$

We must now choose $A$ so that $f(0)=1$. This is equivalent to
$$ 1 = A - \frac{4}{9} $$
and so we get that
$$ A = \frac{13}{9} $$

Thus the solution to the recurrence relation is
$$ f(n) = \frac{1}{9} \left(13 \cdot 4^n - 3n - 4 \right) $$
for all $n$.

You now just need to show that this solution is $O(4^n)$.

Comment: Very nice. I haven't seen that sort of thing before. This is my first discrete math class. I'm starting to see the power of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can been proved like this

$$k(n)=f(n)-f(n-1)=3f(n-1)+n$$
$$k(n-1)=f(n-1)-f(n-2)=3f(n-1)+n-1$$
So
$$k(n)=4k(n-1)+1$$

let
$$g(n)=k(n)-k(n-1)=3g(n-1)+1$$
$$g(n-1)=k(n-1)-k(n-2)=3g(n-1)+1$$
so
$$g(n)=4g(n-1)$$
use 
$$f(0)=1, k(1)=4, k(2)=17, g(2)=13$$
so
$$g(n)=13 \times 4^{n-2},n>1$$
and
$$k(n)=g(n)+k(n-1)=g(n)+g(n-1)+k(n-2)...$$
so
$$k(n)=\sum _{i=2}^n 13 \times 4^{i-2}+k(1))=\frac{13}{3}\times (4^{n-1}-1)+4,n>1$$
and
$$f(n)=k(n)+f(n-1)=k(n)+k(n-1)+f(n-2)...$$
so
$$f(n)=\sum _{i=2}^n\left( (\frac{13}{3}\times (4^{n-1}-1)+4)\right)+k(1)+f(0))=\frac{1}{9}(13\times 4^n -3n-49) + 5,n>1$$
so
$$f(n)<2\times 4^n$$